# Rehsarper 2018.2.3 Disbale inserting new line between summary and single line comment

Tags: resharper, summary, code-cleanup

I'm not able to find the right setting to disable the automatically inserting of a new line between a documentation header summary and a single line comment on code clean up.

For example i have the following code:

```
    /// <summary> The get data from source. </summary>
    /// <returns> The source data. </returns>
    // ReSharper disable once MethodTooLong
    protected override IDictionary<string, Object> GetData()...
```

After clean up code (CTRL+E+F) the result is:

```
    /// <summary> The get data from source. </summary>
    /// <returns> The source data. </returns>

    // ReSharper disable once MethodTooLong
    protected override IDictionary<string, Object> GetData()...
```

How can i get rid of the automatically inserted blank line?

Answer (score 0):

Quite late, but for future:

On Resharper 2018.2.3

Resharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Blank Lines : Blank Lines in Declarations : After File header comment = 0

As you also have a comment, make sure you have Resharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Blank Lines : General : Before single-line comment = 0